# Spark Dataframe UDAF issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Error while decoding:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: failed to
compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 
'generated.java', Line 58, Column 33: Incompatible expression types "boolean" 
and "java.lang.Boolean"
```

Find code over here  [issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20176](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20176)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post code details here and steps to replicate the issue.

And also make sure that spark and scala version are correct in your project.

Example:

scala.version : 2.11.5

scala.compat.version : 2.11

spark.version : 2.1.0

Comment: Please find the code over here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20176